# How to make the connection between PK and FK in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, where-clause, primary-key

I need to make the connection with the PK from a table to its correspondent FK from another table. This is my db:

[image]

I only have the `case_id` from the `case` table, and I need the `case_uid` from the `case_test` table for this SQL statement:

```
UPDATE case_test (this part is ok)
SET country = 'Canada' (this part is ok)
WHERE case_test.case_uid = case.case_uid  (is the same as case_uid from the case table but i only know the case_id field from that table)
```

How can I make the connection between the keys knowing that I only know case_id?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using, and what exactly do you mean with "make the connection between the keys"?

Comment: I'm using PGAdmin. But the idea behind this question is that I give an input payload into a (AWS Step Function) workflow, where I have a Lambda, and there it comes the case_id within the event (=input payload) and I need to make the connection. So for example, case_id = 5, I need to get the case_uid (but they are in the same table = case), in order to look into the case_test table and update the country only on that specific line.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL. [mre] [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [scalar subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES) to extract `case_uid` from table `case`.

```sql
update case_test
set country = 'Canada'
where case_uid = (select case_uid from "case" where case_id = ?);
```

Btw. could it be that there is more than one `case_uid` for a `case_id` in table `case`? If so then the subquery is not scalar anymore and the `where` clause shall use `in` operator instead of `=`

```sql
where case_uid in (select case_uid from "case" where case_id = ?)
```

Unrelated but `case` is not a proper name for a table.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is very clear. I just need one more help, please, because I am confused. Why does it show me " ERROR:  column "c228" does not exist " when I write c228 instead of "?"  ?

Comment: I checked and c228 exists within the column named case_id. But the machine sees it as a column, which is quite strange.

Comment: As the type of column `case_id` is text write 'c228', in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER: Use at your own risk!
Ensure you have a backup before executing the UPDATE statement below.
Check the inner EXISTS SELECT statement before applying the update.

```
UPDATE
    case_test
SET
    country = 'Canada'
WHERE 
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            ct2.case_test_id  /* EXISTS function returns TRUE if any row is returned, so you can use any column or literal value in SELECT body */
        FROM
            case_test AS ct2 /* you need to give an alias inside EXISTS function to not conflicts with the UPDATE table name */
            INNER JOIN
            case AS c2 /* The same here for an alias */
                ON  c2.case_uid = ct2.case_uid
        WHERE
            ct2.case_uid = case_test.case_uid  /* Here the link between the PK of outer case_test table from UPDATE and case_test (as ct2) inside this EXISTS function */
            AND c2.case_id = ? /* Here you set your case_id know value */
    )
```